What do you call a person who takes a casual acquaintance's family tragedy and pretends it’s their own?
A person’s infant child died recently. An unrelated person who knows the bereaved person has gone on social media with the story, but has altered the identities in question and is [falsely] saying that this has actually all happened to their son. This person seems to be basking in the love and attention attendant on concerned posts.
What do you call someone who behaves in this manner?

It sounds like Munchausen syndrome, although it's not a perfect fit. It seems the woman is lonely and ill, have pity on her. I'm sure her own son and daughter-in-law are unhappy to explain to friends and acquaintances that their child (if they do have one) is perfectly healthy.

Psychologists may identify this behavior as emotional contagion or projective identification.

Reading the original version of this question, I'm going to say that there's no one word that sums up this story neatly. Many words are useful in talking about it (identity theft, invasion of privacy, exploitation, etc.), and many descriptors might be appropriate for such a person (attention-seeker, unscrupulous, fraudster). But none of these paints the whole picture. I recommend giving up on encapsulating the whole story in one word and focusing on simply telling it as concisely and impactfully as possible.

Also: this question and the ones it links to might be useful.

I don't think this is a common enough behavior to have a specific name for it. They're just a liar -- the fact that what they described happened to a friend hardly seems relevant.

Sympathy whore (Urban Dictionary) is the closest I found. But I wouldn't normally say that. Sympathy snatcher can mean one with Factitious Disorder (or HPD, possibly) and sympathy stealer can mean sympathy exploiter (done for personal gain, money, etc.).

I hope that there are few enough people like this to have generated a specific form of words for this.  Qualities of this kind require the art of a good writer to capture in words, not of a lexicographer.

Wikipedia defines sadfishing as "a behavioural trend where people make exaggerated claims about their emotional problems to generate sympathy." It's a form of attention-seeking behaviour.
The name is derived from catfishing, the creation of a fictitious online persona for other purposes (deception, trolling, revenge, boredom, etc).
Sadfishing isn't a very widely used term; Wikipedia says it dates back to 2019, and it's not yet made many dictionaries although Wiktionary has an entry. It has got coverage in the leading popular psychology publication Psychology Today in 2021, Forbes in 2024, the UK Independent in 2024, and the other sources referenced in the Wikipedia article.

Does 'sadfishing' necessarily involve 'identity theft' (in the broadest sense)?

Sadfisher would be the noun, and I did find it online while searching "sympathy seeker." It's hard to nail down the specific method, but thumps up.

Medically it is known as Munchausen syndrome

Munchausen syndrome is a factitious disorder in which those affected feign […] psychological trauma to draw attention, sympathy, or reassurance to themselves.

Munchausen -> Pron: /mʌntʃˈhaʊzɛn/
